# How to access variables in an erb-subtemplate in puppet?

Tags: puppet

example.pp

```
$foo = 'bar'
$content = template('mymodule/maintemplate.erb')
```

maintemplate.erb

```
<% bar = foo + "extra" %>

foobar = scope_function_template(['mymodule/subtemplate.erb'])
```

subtemplate.erb

```
<%# here i want to access the variable bar %>
<%= bar %>
```

there is the function

```
<%= scope.lookupvar('::bar') %>
```

is there a kind of `parent::bar` in erb templateing, or can i pass some variables to the subtemplate, or can i only access the outer variable (of the .pp file) with `::foo`

Comment: check http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6492

Comment: @rbtux thank you very much. can you add it as answer so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in this bugreport/feature request: http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6492 there is a workaround using `scope.setvar`

```
<% bar = foo + "extra" %>
scope.unsetvar('bar')
scope.setvar('bar',bar)
```

This is ugly but seems to work...

Comment: `scope.unsetvar()` was removed in https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/commit/43a5754ad51e73d3a4ac13309b4ebeec0103b1c7 and is not available in puppet 3.x

Answer (score 0):

So I read at http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6592#note-6 that a TemplateWrapper could be used and I end up with this snippet:

```
<%
newscope = scope.compiler.newscope(scope)
newscope.setvar(k, v)
wrapper = Puppet::Parser::TemplateWrapper.new(newscope)
wrapper.file = 'templatefile.erb'
%>
<%= wrapper.result %>
```